# Remove liquid trapped under glass

Tags: glass

If I have a table with a glass inset, and this inset is sealed/glued into the frame, but I spilled some tea and it somehow seeped under, what might be the best way to dry or remove that tea?

Comment: Could you please add a photo? And: Welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were a small object, I would recommend a process similar to [rice for a drowned mobile phone](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7108/15), but since we're dealing with a table, we need to move the solution to the problem.

Use a hair dryer to help evaporate the droplets. Once they condense, tilt the table to bring all moisture to one corner of the frame. Repeat the process again several times as the evaporated droplets will escape through the frame (a way in means a way out).

The issue comes if the tea contained water or milk, or is enough to stain the inside of the glass. Then you will have to remove the glass entirely. A heat gun may be useful to melt glue, but be sure to take precautions as to not shatter the glass itself.