# How to safely remove the glass from a wooden table with glass top?

Tags: home, glass

I have a wooden table with a glass top:

[image]

I want to remove the glass top safely not to injure myself, breaking glass is possible, looks like the glass is glued to the wood.

How can I do that?

Comment: Anyway, the question now is: why you want to remove it? What's the goal?

Comment: could you suggest please, as i am translating from different language.

Comment: just want to remove, dont ask the goal)))

Comment: Well the answer [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/19865/remove-liquid-trapped-under-glass) might help you a bit, it suggest using a heat gun to remove the glue.

Comment: Edit suggested.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have a heat gun)) i thought about the hammer, just break the glass, not  sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Buy a strong [Duct tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_tape): (**Not the simple transparent used for paper**.)

   [image]
2. Wrap the whole glass with the duct tape, make sure to not leave any uncovered spot.
3. Get a hammer, the bigger the better:

   [image]
4. Hit the glass wrapped with duct tape with the hammer, but not too strong as to not break the wood underneath the glass.
5. Get thick **woodworking** gloves:

   [image]
6. Pick the broken pieces and dispose of them in a trash container, better inside a strong nylon bag.

Answer (score 3):

I would NOT try to pry the glass off. Here is what I would try if I had to attempt this:

Find some very thing wire (piano wire, or wire for haning pictures on walls). Get a piece longer than the width of the glass. Create loops in the ends so I can pull the wire. Then with a sort of sawing motion, try to work the wire under the glass... all the way across the entire table. This would be painfully slow... but it's the only way I can think to "break" the glue under the glass.

I suspect that it would quickly be obvious after a few inches if this was going to work.

This won't remove the glue—the table will have glue on it of course. But it MIGHT separate the glass from the table.

Comment: This is a good idea, but you will hurt your hands if you create loops in the end of the wire. I recommend this: get 2 small pieces of wood, the size of a mouse, and tie the ends of the wire around them. Then pull on the wood instead of the wire!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a air tight cup to remove the glass from a table ,this method is very easy and quickly

Comment: This would work for an unattached tabletop, but the glass is glued to the wood frame.